# space complexity of iterative binary search

Tags: data-structures, big-o, binary-search-tree, space-complexity

I'm trying to understand the space complexity of iterative binary search. Given the space complexity is input size + auxiliary space, shouldn't the space complexity depend on the input size? why is it always O(1)?
If we compare the space complexity between tree A(the height of the tree is 1) and tree B(the height of the tree is 1,000) I think the space complexity should be different. Could someone please explain me why it should be the same regardless of the input size?

Comment: The space for keeping the data is definatly depenent on the data size. If you have a source that claims binary search in a tree requires O(1) space, it means **in addition** to storing the data (which is true).

Comment: There are different definitions. Usually "space complexity" is further qualified as "**auxiliary** space complexity", because the input is not part of the algorithm -- there is nothing you can change in the algorithm to improve on that space use. So the focus is on this *auxiliary* space use. Some authors might use "space complexity" in this sense without this qualification.

Comment: @trincot in fact qualification is never necessary.  If a stated space complexity could be less than the input size, then it obviously doesn't include the input.  Otherwise it doesn't matter whether it in includes the input or not.

Comment: Yes, the qualification is optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Given the space complexity is input size + auxiliary space...

Yes, but this premise is incorrect.  I checked the Web and there seem to be a lot of sites that define space complexity this way, and then go on to mention sublinear space complexities as if there were no contradiction.  It's no wonder that people are confused.

This definition is really just wrong, because **it is always correct to interpret a space complexity as referring to auxiliary space only.**

If a stated space complexity is sublinear, then it obviously cannot include the input space, so you should interpret it as referring to auxiliary space only.

If a stated space complexity is *not* sublinear, then it is correct whether it includes the input space or not, and in fact it means exactly the same thing in both cases, so you can't go wrong by assuming that it refers to auxiliary space only.

Including the input space in your definition of space complexity can only *reduce* the set of complexity statements that your definition applies to, and the meaning when it does apply is unchanged, so that makes it *strictly less correct* as a definition.