# Why do space complexity analysis not involve output space?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, space-complexity

In the space complexity analysis of the famous program - Running sum of 1-D array, it is observed that the space complexity is O(N) irrespective of returning the solution in the same array or returning the solution in a newly created array.

Even when the program specifies to return the array as an output, why is there no difference in space complexity analysis between these two cases?

Approach 1: Solution with new array as output

```
public static int[] runningSum(int[] nums) {
        int[] sum= new int[nums.length];

        sum[0]=nums[0];

        for(int i=1;i<nums.length;i++){
            sum[i]= nums[i]+sum[i-1];
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

Approach 2: Solution with input array as output

```
    public static int[] runningSumReturnSameArray(int[] nums) {
        for(int i=1; i< nums.length;i++){
            nums[i]=nums[i-1]+nums[i];
        }
        return nums;
    }
```

Approach 1 and Approach 2 have difference in the space and hence i am expecting it to have difference in respective space complexities.

Comment: Approach 2 has space complexity is O(1) since no space is allocated (except a constant number of bytes for local variables etc which is independent of `n`).

Comment: *"it is observed that..."*: source?

Comment: @trincot : This is from https://leetcode.com/problems/running-sum-of-1d-array/editorial/

Comment: Cannot open that link. Please quote the statement literally in our question, with enough context.

Comment: Approach 2 has O(1) space complexity.  You seem to have figured this out already.  Remember that nobody has to pass any kind of certification test before they can write stuff on the internet.

Comment: @MattTimmermans So [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity?wprov=sfla1) is wrong? It says space complexity *"includes the memory space used by its inputs"*.

Comment: @KellyBundy Practically yes.  More specifically, it is always correct to interpret a statement of space complexity as referring to auxiliary space only, and always unnecessary to indicate that a statement of space complexity refers to auxiliary space only, and so that is the practical definition.  I tried to explain in longer form here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73424209/space-complexity-of-iterative-binary-search/73427868#73427868

Comment: @MattTimmermans Do you have any source for that? Looks like it's just your own opinion.

Comment: It's an argument.

Answer (score 0):

You should know the difference between space complexity and extra space complexity. We often use the definition of "space complexity" assuming actually extra space. Extra space is space that we allocate only for algorithm runtime.

The actual space complexity of both approaches is *O(n)* because we also count the input data.

But extra space complexity is different:

For approach 1 it is *O(n)*

For approach 2 it is *O(1)*

Answer (score -1):

Both have the same Time complexity O(n).

**Space complexity**: is the amount of memory space required relative to the size of the input.

for Approach 1:
Space complexity is O( n )

means we add memory space in this function of size n ;  where n is the size of input

for Approach 2:
Space complexity is O( 1 )

since the function space usage remains constant regardless of the input size.

I hope this help